# How to use an Azure Key Vault rolling certificate with OpenIddict?

Tags: azure-keyvault, x509certificate2, openiddict

`IdentityServer` allows you to register a `ISigningCredentialStore` and a `IValidationKeysStore`, which in turn enables dynamic loading of certificates from, for example, Azure Key Vault because the certificate store is called each time which handles lifetime, caching, updating etc.

What is the equivalent to achieve the same in `OpenIddict`?